# Highcharts plotOptions.area.depth does not exist in latest version

Tags: highcharts

The HighCharts demo for 3D Area Charts: https://www.highcharts.com/demo/3d-area-multiple

Uses `plotOptions.area.depth` to render multiple series stacked one behind another.  The latest version of HighCharts doesn't honor this setting, and the Typescript Definitions says it does not exist.  It will also throw this Error in the console:
`Type ‘{ depth: number; }’ is not assignable to type ‘PlotAreaOptions’.`

How do we configure this feature now?

For what it's worth, that depth setting is honored by other 3D chart types.

Comment: Just to be sure, I'd like to ask you if you didn't mean to set the depth of options3d like in this [link](https://api.highcharts.com/highcharts/chart.options3d.depth), right?

Comment: That isn't the same setting despite the same name, that sets the depth of the entire chart, but the Area and Area Spline charts are still rendered on top of each other despite the value set to that option.

Answer (score 1):

This does not look like a regression problem with the new version of Highcharts.

In this case, you need to extend your type in your TypeScript project.
I have created an example with Angular showing how to extend the type at Highcharts 3d area.

Implementation of interface with missing types:

```
interface ExtendedPlotAreaOptions extends Highcharts.PlotAreaOptions {
  depth: number; marker: { enabled: false; }; states: { inactive: { enabled: false; }; };
}
```

Example of extending area options:

```
plotOptions: {
  area: {
    depth: 300,
    marker: {
      enabled: false
    },
    states: {
      inactive: {
        enabled: false
      }
    }
  } as ExtendedPlotAreaOptions
},
```

Live demo:
https://stackblitz.com/edit/highcharts-angular-basic-line-uphers?file=src%2Fapp%2Fapp.component.ts

API Refereneces:
https://www.highcharts.com/docs/advanced-chart-features/highcharts-typescript-declarations#solving-problems

Comment: What you are suggesting for us to do would only fix a compile time error, which we've done by casting the config to `any`.   If you didn't have a working example, I would have dismissed it completely.  :) That said, I'm starting to wonder if we have another X or Y axis setting that is breaking that option.   Because even with your suggestion, which is better than casting to `any`, our area charts are still rendered without space between them.  We'll start removing chart options until something changes. And report back here if we narrow it down.

Comment: Marking this as correct, as it does make for a better development environment experience.  As it turns out we had some code turning on "stacked" area -- and the data was so random it wasn't obvious.  It appeared as if the series were pancaked instead of spread out.  Once that option was turned off, it did behave like the example.

If any HighCharts employees read this, it would be nice if you could get your Typescript Definitions updated soon with the API changes.